# Question about cusp cubic example in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, in Chapter II.6 on Divisors he computes the Cartier class group (denoted $\operatorname{CaCl}$) of the cuspidal cubic cut out by $y^2z=x^3$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. He claims that there is a surjective degree homomorphism $\operatorname{CaCl}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, and that there is a one to one correspondence between non-singular closed points of the cuspidal cubic and the kernel of the degree map.

I am confused about his proof of this statement. In particular, he begins with "note that any Cartier divisor is linearly equivalent to one whose local function in some neighborhood of the singular point $Z=(0,0,1)$". How can he do that? Could you do that for any curve and argument that the points in the kernel of the degree map are in one to one correspondence with the all closed points but that one (but the same correspondence would not work). I guess part of my question is where in the proof does he actually use the cuspness?

Any clarification would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: The first bit is general: Any Cartier divisor is linearly equivalent to one whose local function is invertible in a neighborhood of a given point (see the definition p. 141 and adjust by an appropriate element of K^*). The other stuff depends on the curves having degree 3, since in that case a sum of collinear points is 0 in the group law. It won't work for a curve, smooth or not, of degree 4, for example. You can do the same for a nodal cubic.

Comment: A followup question that may help me understand is: how exactly does the cusp point behave. Does it behave like a double point or something else? Is the ideal sheaf of the cusp even invertible?

Comment: It is definitely a double point: A general line, say y=mx for simplicity, meets it in the scheme k[x]/m^2x^2-x^3 = k[x]/x^2. The ideal sheaf of that point is (therefore) not Cartier; there is no single equation that cuts it out (scheme-theoretically) locally.